# How to store state of tabs based on route?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

Is it possible to store different state of a `<v-tab>` component based on the route i'm currently on? What i'm basically trying to achieve is, have a single component like the code below that i use in several different routes, but have it remember the tab i'm currently at depending on the route.

```
  <v-layout justify-space-around row>
    <v-tab v-for="tab in navbarTabs" :key="tab.id">{{ tab.name }}</v-tab>
  </v-layout>

data() {
 return {
    navbarTabs: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Home"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Schedule"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Tech card"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Specifications"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Control card"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Packing"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

I previously managed to achieve the desired result by having a few identical `<v-tab>` components that i visualised conditionally based on current route with `v-if`, but that solutions seems a bit crude and not scalable at all.
Can someone give me some pointers on how to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [`keep-alive` with dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)?

Comment: I used `keep-alive` before while i had 4 instances of the `<v-tab>` that i conditionally rendered as "dynamic" components based on route, but with a single component it does not appear to work.

Comment: Not sure I understand: do you need to a certain tab to be open depending on the route? For example if the route is `/tabs/1`  then the tab with id 1 should be open?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Yes, what i'm trying to achieve is: While im at `route1` and i go the tab with the id of 3, for example, if i'm at `route2` and i go the tab with the id of 2, the tab at `route1` to still be id 3. 
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: All right. Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Yes i am, but what the `<v-tabs>` component does is is:
You define 
`<v-tab v-for="tab in navbarTabs" :key="tab.id" class="navbarRouters">{{ tab.name }}</v-tab>`
And then, you just place components beneath it encapsulated in `<v-tab-item>`, you dont actually go to different routes.
I'm however open to a solution that implements the Vue Router.
I'm also using Vuex, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `v-tabs` component has a `value` prop which you can use to open a tab with a given `key`. And the `v-tab` component has a `to` prop which you can use to set the route of a tab. So essentially, you can use Vue Router params to select a tab and you can set the route using the `v-tab`'s `to` prop.

You can define your route like this to pass the `selectedTab` param to the component:

```
 routes: [
    { path: '/tabs/:selectedTab', component: TabsComponent, props: true },
 ]
```

And your `TabsComponent` can look something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-layout justify-space-around row>
     <v-tabs v-model="selectedTab">
       <v-tab 
         v-for="tab in navbarTabs"
         :key="tab.id"
         :to=`/tabs/${tab.id}`
       >{{ tab.name }}</v-tab>
     </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['selectedTab'],
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to answer my question, miss! You are a lifesaver!